# Why Is My Rendered Image Distorted?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

When I animate everything looks normal here:
[image]

But then I render it with <kbd>F12</kbd> it looks like this:
[image]

Why is that?
I'm a beginner and not a native-english-speaker. So sorry if I get a bit confused.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! It appears to me that in the rendering dialog, you are zoomed in. Try to scroll with the mouse wheel, that shoud show the rest of the image.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your images, you are looking at your scene through the *LookDev* (A.K.A "Material Preview") tab. This is a setting that provides artificial lighting (not made by you) to the scene to be able to quickly preview things, but does not represent the way your scene actually is lit. To see how your scene will appear when rendered, you should preview your scene through the *Rendered Preview* display tab. See below:

[image: Viewing]

Comment: I don't think lookdev mode will cause the camera to be zoomed in and slightly rotated. Compare the two images, you can see rendered view has a noticeably smaller fov.

Comment: Sometimes when you render, the final result is slightly larger than your screen, scroll the mouse wheel to zoom out a bit. The render should be the result of everything inside the "dark box" in the top image. As for the rotation - It looks slightly rotated in both the images, maybe it's just more pronounced when zoomed in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it didn't solve my problem. I still don't know why it is distorted...

Comment: Hmmmm. Could you clarify what you mean by "distorted"? Do you mean all the noise (black and white dots)?

Comment: I think the problem you are having is this - You are using Cycles rendering engine for your scene, but are looking at it through the Material Preview (LookDev) setting. This preview uses a renderer more similar to EEVEE to render the preview more quickly. However, when you render your image, you are getting a Cycles (path traced) render, which is not the same as what you are seeing in your preview window. If you want the final render to look more like the preview, switch your rendering engine to EEVEE.

Comment: Thank you! It worked.